# Lock/Condition with AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, locking

I am kinda rusty with locking, and I am trying to make a simple network communication on my android app.  Needless to say, you have to use `AsyncTask` in android to do these communications.  How can I lock the main thread until the `AsyncTask` is done?

```
public int read(){
    ReadTCPTask t = new ReadTCPTask();
    boolean canGoOn = false;
    // We can proceed once we acquire the lock?
    while (!canGoOn)
        canGoOn = lock.tryLock();
    t.execute();
    // something that will wait here until the asynctask is done?
    return readSize;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way IMO is to declare your `AsyncTask` and store a reference to it:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.execute();
```

Then where you want it to block until `AsyncTask` completion call:

```
task.get();
```

That's it!

Although, blocking the main thread is probably not the way you want to go about this.  It is more common to use a callback from the `AsyncTask` to update the main thread when it completes.

Comment: For testing purposes this is working.  Will look into callbacks later on when I am actually using this in a real system.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main purpose of `AsyncTask` is not to block the main thread. `AsyncTask` is designed to make the communication between UI and non-UI threads easier. So, if you want to block the UI thread, you can just write the statements in the `Activity` itself.